# Show $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2^n}\geq -\frac{\ln(-\ln(x))}{e\ln(2)}$ for all $x\in(\frac{1}{e},1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

I am trying to show the inequality
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2^n}\geq -\frac{\ln(-\ln(x))}{e\ln(2)}$$
for $x\in(\frac{1}{e},1)$.

I have observed that the inequality
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2^n}\geq\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-1-n\ln(2)}(-\ln(-\ln(x)))$$
appears to hold, and from this right hand side I believe it is possible to use integral comparisons to obtain the desired inequality.

However, I have been unsuccessful in showing this inequality since it appears that it does not hold term-wise (i.e. it appears that we don't have $x^{2^n}\geq e^{-1-n\ln(2)}(-\ln(-\ln(x)))$ for all relevant $x$ and $n$). Maybe there is an easier approach to the original problem?

Comment: How did you come up with the RHS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $\frac{1}{\mathrm e}<x<1$. Then
$$
x^{2^n }  \ge \int_n^{n + 1} {x^{2^t } {\rm d}t} 
$$
for any $n\ge 0$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {x^{2^n } }  \ge \int_0^{ + \infty } {x^{2^t } {\rm d}t} & = \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{2^t \log x} {\rm d}t}  = \frac{1}{{\log 2}}\int_1^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - s( - \log x)} }}{s}{\rm d}s} \\ & = \frac{1}{{\log 2}}\int_{ - \log x}^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - u} }}{u}{\rm d}u}  \ge \frac{1}{{\log 2}}\int_{ - \log x}^{ 1 } {\frac{{{\rm e}^{ - u} }}{u}{\rm d}u} \\ & \ge\frac{1}{{\mathrm{e}\log 2}}\int_{ - \log x}^{ 1 } {\frac{{\rm d}u}{u}} =-\frac{\log(-\log x)}{\mathrm{e}\log 2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice and elementary! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Up to and including Equation \eqref{eq3}, the following is true for all $\ x\in \left( 0, 1 \right),\ $ not just for $\ x\in \left( \frac{1}{e}, 1 \right).$

$$ 1-x \leq -\ln x. $$

Since $\ln$ is increasing, this implies $\ \ln(1-x) \leq \ln(-\ln x),\ $ which implies,

$$-\ln(-\ln x) \leq -\ln(1-x). \tag{1}\label{eq1}  $$

Next, recall that,

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n} = -\ln(1-x). \tag{2}\label{eq2} $$

Using [Cauchy condensation estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test#Estimate) with $f(n) = \frac{x^n}{n}, $ we have:

$$\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n} \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{2^n}} \leq 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n}. \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

Putting $\eqref{eq1},\ \eqref{eq2},\ $ and $\ \eqref{eq3}\ $ together whilst also noting that $e\ln 2>1;\ $ therefore as Gary pointed out in the comments, in order for the very last inequality to hold, we need $\ x > \frac{1}{e},\ $ we have on $\ x\in \left( \frac{1}{e}, 1 \right),$

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{2^n} \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n} = -\ln(1-x) \geq -\ln(-\ln x) \geq -\frac{\ln(-\ln x)}{e\ln 2}. $$

Comment: $-\ln(-\ln x) \geq -\frac{\ln(-\ln x)}{e\ln 2}$ is where you need $x>\frac{1}{\mathrm e}$.

Comment: Not sure if I did the tags correctly. Someone please fix it if it is causing viewing issues.

Comment: @Gary well spotted, thanks.

Comment: I mean the equation tags (in my second previous comment).

Answer (score 0):

*Alternative solution.*

- If $x \in (\mathrm{e}^{-1}, 9/10]$, it suffices to prove that
  $$x + x^2 \ge - \frac{\ln(-\ln x)}{\mathrm{e}\ln 2}$$
  or (using $x^2 \ge \mathrm{e}^{-1}x$)
  $$x + \mathrm{e}^{-1}x \ge - \frac{\ln(-\ln x)}{\mathrm{e}\ln 2}. \tag{1}$$
  Let $f(x) := x + \mathrm{e}^{-1}x + \frac{\ln(-\ln x)}{\mathrm{e}\ln 2}$.
  We have
  $f'(x) = 1 + \mathrm{e}^{-1} + \frac{1}{x\ln x \cdot \mathrm{e}\ln 2} < 0$.
  Also, $f(9/10) > 0$. Thus, $f(x) > 0$ on $(\mathrm{e}^{-1}, 9/10]$.
- If $x \in (9/10, 1)$, letting $N := \lfloor -\frac{\ln(-\ln x)}{\mathrm{e}\ln 2} \rfloor$, it suffices to prove that
  $$\sum_{n=0}^{N + 1} x^{2^n} \ge -\frac{\ln(-\ln x)}{\mathrm{e}\ln 2}$$
  or (using $x^{2^n} = \mathrm{e}^{2^n \ln x} \ge  1 + 2^n \ln x$)
  $$\sum_{n=0}^{N + 1} (1 + 2^n \ln x) \ge -\frac{\ln(-\ln x)}{\mathrm{e}\ln 2}$$
  or
  $$N + 2 + (2^{N+2} - 1)\ln x 
  \ge -\frac{\ln(-\ln x)}{\mathrm{e}\ln 2}$$
  or (using $-\frac{\ln(-\ln x)}{\mathrm{e}\ln 2} - 1 \le N \le -\frac{\ln(-\ln x)}{\mathrm{e}\ln 2}$)
  $$\left(-\frac{\ln(-\ln x)}{\mathrm{e}\ln 2} - 1\right) + 2 + (2^{-\frac{\ln(-\ln x)}{\mathrm{e}\ln 2} + 2} - 1)\ln x \ge -\frac{\ln(-\ln x)}{\mathrm{e}\ln 2}$$
  or
  $$1 + (2^{-\frac{\ln(-\ln x)}{\mathrm{e}\ln 2} + 2} - 1)\ln x \ge 0$$
  or
  $$1 + \left(4 (-\ln x)^{-\mathrm{e}^{-1}} -1\right)\ln x \ge 0. \tag{2}$$
  Letting $y = -\ln x$, it suffices to prove that, for all $y \in (0, -\ln\frac{9}{10})$,
  $$1 - (4 y^{-\mathrm{e}^{-1}} - 1)y \ge 0$$
  or
  $$g(y) := 1 + y - 4y^{1 - \mathrm{e}^{-1}} \ge 0. \tag{3}$$
  We have $g'(y) = 1 - 4(1 - \mathrm{e}^{-1})y^{-\mathrm{e}^{-1}} < 0$.
  Also, $g(-\ln\frac{9}{10}) > 0$. Thus, $g(y) \ge 0$ on $(0, -\ln\frac{9}{10})$.

We are done.